# Text disappearing and reappearing

Tags: terminal, lxqt

I'm running Lubuntu 22.04. Occasionally, when I type, a portion of the text near to the end of my line disappears and reappears repeatedly. I tried using `xev` to check for any misfiring keys buts I could not see anything. What could be causing this?

**Edit:** sometimes when I right click something in firefox, and left click to close the highlighted text, the right click menu reappears or reappears again for a second time and then disappear, it can also appear and reappear multiple times.

Also, when I attempt to unhighlight text, the text will rehighlight for a second before re-highlighting.

Rebooting or disconnecting my usb mouse does not appear to fix the issue.

Comment: Sounds like a Problem in your Display Hardware and/or Driver. (1) Check with some other hardware or connect to your HDMI TV via Dual Monitor (2) Check whether Display Driver Updates are available.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a problem with the display driver because I can watch videos fine on the laptop, and there are no problems with the display in general (except a bit of screen tearing).

Comment: You mention Screen tearing ; It makes me still think about **Display Issues** .... Continuing my earlier comment , I want to add (3) Change the Screen resolution + refresh rate & whether Issue Increases or Decreases (4) Rotate by 90 or 180 & Check where the Issue/tearing occurs.

Comment: Still more to try (5) Boot into Windows via Dual Boot or some other Linux via Live CD & check whether Issue occurs (6) Connect to your laptop over XServer using some other "working" system & check whether Issue still occurs on "working" system. These six activities are very simple and easy enough to try & will eliminate some Possibilities to narrow down the Issue !! Mostly, I am thinking that **"Display Hardware or Driver"** is the Issue here.

Comment: Hi, I'm, coincidentally, about to boot into ubuntu. If the issue persists I'll try the rest of the troubleshooting tips.

Comment: I hope the reboot went fine